# Datatables Array with objects

Tags: javascript, datatables

Im trying to parse data from AJAX to datatables

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#table').dataTable({
      'serverSide': true,
      'ajax': {
        'url': 'url',
        'type': 'GET',
        'beforeSend': function (request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(self.username + ":" + self.password));
        },
        'dataSrc': function (data) {
          console.log(data["value"]);
          return (data["value"]);
        },
        columns: [
           { value: "completedDate" }
        ]
      }
   });
});
```

In my console log i see the structure of the array:

Object
count:134
value:Array[134]
[0 … 99]
0:Object
completedDate
:
"2017-01-20T12:33:49.203Z"

What is the way to map the `completedDate` to a column?

I see no errors.
The strange thing is that the page numbers "Showing 1 to 10 of 134 entries" are correct, but the records are empty:

[image: empty records]

Comment: I get this: DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with row.add:

```
var completedDate = data1["value"][0]["completedDate"];
table.rows.add([{
    "completedDate":completedDate,
}]).draw();`
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
columns: [
    { data: "completedDate" }
]
```

Also I doubt you're using server-side processing so I think you can remove `'serverSide': true`.

Comment: i get this error "DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" but i see empty records now.

Comment: No error in my network tab, only in the alert: DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: @Janp95, Please post an excerpt from server-side response (Network tab -> Response) for your `GET` request.

Comment: I get the array with results back: `{"count":134,"value":[{"id":9163,"name":"test },{"id":9165,"name":"test etc.`

Comment: @Janp95, I don't see `completedDate` in the response so use either `id` or `name` since those are the only properties that you have.

Comment: I removed that for this example, `{ data: "name" }` also didn't work